# In a two-node Kubernetes cluster, is it expected that when one node goes down, kube-apiserver stops listening on the other node?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a little two-node Kubernetes cluster. Both nodes are masters, running their own etcd, and running workloads (without the taint).

I have noticed that when I reboot one node, the other's kubectl ceases to work, even though the kubeconfig is pointed at the server that is still running. That is because, apparently, the server is no longer listening on port 6443.

When the server that was rebooted comes back online, it too cannot use kubectl, and it too is not listening on port 6443.

I typically intervene by stopping docker and kubelet, flushing iptables, and starting them again. This gives it a kick in the can I guess.

But my questions are as follows:

1. Is it normal for the other node's apiserver to stop listening on port 6443 when you reboot a node of a two-node self-etcd-hosted Kubernetes cluster?
2. If I wait long enough, after rebooting, will apiserver come back? (Without my intervention)
3. If so, how does that work? How often does it retry to start kube-apiserver again?
4. If I had three nodes, would none of this occur with a single-node reboot?

Comment: if you are running etcd on the masters, the minimum number of nodes, that you could have is 3, due to the fact, the etcd cluster uses quorum

Comment: How did you setup your cluster?

Comment: @c4f4t0r that's only partially true -- you can have an single etcd member, AFAIK, but you just don't want an _even_ number of them; so 1, 3, 5 ...